# Branches: current vs stable vs release

Tags: git, github, apache-zookeeper

[Here at this Apache Zookeeper mirror site](http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/apache/zookeeper/) there is a current branch, a stable branch, and then there are release versions. Inside of the current directory there is `zookeeper-3.4.9.tar.gz`, inside of the stable directory is `zookeeper-3.4.9.tar.gz`, and then there is also a release version of `zookeeper-3.4.9.tar.gz`. Typically, what are the differences between a branch called current, a branch called stable, and a release branch? Also, are those differences conventional in the industry?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly reference link is https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/branches

[image]

> Active branches: The Active view shows all branches that anyone has
>   committed to within the last **three months**, ordered by the branches
>   with the most recent commits first.
>
> Stale branches: The Stale view shows all branches that no one has
>   committed to in the last **three months**, ordered by the branches with
>   the oldest commits first.

(Source: https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-branches-in-your-repository/)

GitHub has been interpolates by the latest commit time

- A branch has latest commit time **so far**, grouped to `Stable`.
- A branch has latest commit time **near the current time**, it grouped to `Active`.